# Trim output of grep command

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

I used this command to get output But i want to prune the output to see a trimmed-down final result

Result required :

```
EsbDwMarkDownAdbSub "CleClient" "3.1"
EsbDwMarkDownAdbSub "Encrypter" "1.0"
```

Command:

```
grep --color -H -r "__GLOBAL_SUBSTITUTION_VARIABLE__Environment/LibraryVersions" /opt/tibco/product/tra/domain/WFM-DEV 2>/dev/null
```

Output that I see currently :

```
/opt/tibco/product/tra/domain/WFM-DEV/data/EsbDwMarkDownAdbSub.dat:       <instanceInfoPropertyname="__GLOBAL_SUBSTITUTION_VARIABLE__Environment/LibraryVersions/CleClient" value="3.1"/>
/opt/tibco/product/tra/domain/WFM-DEV/data/EsbDwMarkDownAdbSub.dat:    <instanceInfoProperty name="__GLOBAL_SUBSTITUTION_VARIABLE__Environment/LibraryVersions/Encrypter" value="1.0"/>
```

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: You've told us what the required output is and what your current output is, but you didn't tell us what input you were given to work with!

Comment: we can take their output as input by piping it...

Comment: If you don't want filenames in your output, why are you using `-H` with grep?

Comment: @muru I think part of what they want in the output is the basename minus the extension

Answer (score 3):

You could, for example, pipe the result into `sed` (perhaps we could give you a more elegant way knowing your actual input) - add this to the end of your `grep` command:

```
| sed -r 's#.*/(EsbDw[^\.]+).*/([^"]+").*=([^/]+)/>#\1 "\2 \3#'
EsbDwMarkDownAdbSub "CleClient" "3.1"
EsbDwMarkDownAdbSub "Encrypter" "1.0"
```

- `-r` use ERE so we don't have to escape `()` and `+`
- `s#old#new#` replace `old` with `new`
- `.*/` any characters before a `/`
- `(EsbDw[^\.]+)` find a pattern starting with `EsbDw` and ending with a `.` and save everything before the `.`
- `/([^"]+")` any characters between `/` and `"` - save everything after `/` including `"`
- `=([^/]+)/>` save whatever comes between `=` and `/>`
- `\1 "\2 \3` the three saved patterns with spaces between them (and adding one `"`)

Answer (score 3):

Desired output can be done fairly easily with Python2:

```
$ ./trim_lines.py < input.txt                                                                                            
EsbDwMarkDownAdbSub "CleClient" "3.1"
EsbDwMarkDownAdbSub "Encrypter" "1.0"
```

The contents of `trim_lines.py` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys,os,re

for line in sys.stdin:
    words=line.strip().split()
    val1 = os.path.basename(words[0]).split(".")[0]
    val2 = '"' + os.path.basename(words[2])
    val3 = re.split("[=/]",words[-1])[1]
    print val1,val2,val3
```

What happens here is fairly simple. We use `<` to redirect contents of input file to script ( in your case, where input coming from grep use pipe `...| ./trim_lines.py` to send output from `grep` to the script ). The script loops over all lines that come to its stdin stream, splits each line into words, and additionally filters those words using a few built in modules, such as `os.path` and `re`. First two values we obtain use `os.path.basename()`, and last one uses `re.split()` to break down last string at multiple delimiters. There's a lot of things going on here, but believe me - it's quite simple.